# Change link address depending on logged in state

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is check the session to see if a user is logged in or not, then display the appropriate link.

Here's my code:

```
<?
  if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {$login"<a title='Log Out' href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"}
  else
    {$login"<a title='Login' href='login.php'>LOGIN</a>"}
?>

<ul>
..
    <li class='inline'><? echo "$login" ?></li>
</ul>
```

I hope you can help, because I've been trying so many different methods and I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, I assume you're checking to see whether the user is logged in. Is she is, set a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

```
session_start();
if (mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // if user is logged in...
}
```

Then later in your code, when you're preparing the view, prepare the logout/in link by checking that session variable:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
  $anchor = '<a title="Logout" href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
} else {
  $anchor = '<a title="Login" href="login.php">Login</a>';
}
```

Or you could abstract that to a function.

Comment: Quite right, I'm so used to my HTML having double quote attribute wrappers. Thanks!